# How to Animate an EditText from the Center

Tags: java, android, animation, android-edittext, gesture

So I want to animate my `EditText`(ET) to expand. Plain and simple right. Well I can do it with the following code but that is from (left of ET stays in the same position, right of ET expands outwards). I would like it from the center where left and right of ET expands outwards then on any other 
?Gesture or touch of anywhere? not the ET itself, it closes(shrinks) to original size in a animate way. Is there a way to do the following or a library that can help simplify this. If so leave a link all comments will be appreciated due to my entry level knowledge.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<scale
    android:duration="400"
    android:fillAfter="true"        
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" >
</scale>

</set>
```

Comment: add code of your xml which has EditText

Answer (score 0):

to start the animation from the center make

```
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
```

However with you code you are starting the animation from it's original view scale than expand it, you should animate the view from smaller scale to the original scale it should be something like that.

```
android:fromXScale="0.0"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0"
....
```

however, if you want to keep the old code for some reason make sure your `editText` container in `xml` is wide enough you don't want your `editText` to interface with other views

You `EditText` in `xml` sholud be

```
android:layout_width="you_width"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minLines="1"
....
```

Comment: Thank you sorry for the late reply it is correct but I have some new issues that arise
1. it zooms in on the edit text and is distorted
2.the first 4 characters art visible

Comment: I dont get it what you mean by "zoom" and "4 characters are visible" ?

Comment: form the scaling it causes it to become larger and Stretched, when you type a word after the 4th letter you see what you are typing

Comment: @EquiWare I meant edit you question with your code not my answer. however, I edited my answer check the EditText part